# Check page access conditions for MifareUltralight NFC tags on Android

Tags: android, tags, nfc, mifare, lockbits

I already locked specific pages after I wrote one time to a MifareUltralight tag. When I call the `writePage()` the next time, I want to check the access conditions for that page first. If the page is locked, I do not want to call the write method. How could I achieve this on Android?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to read the lock bits and analyze them in order to find out if specific pages are marked as read-only:

```
boolean isPageLocked(MifareUltralight tag, int page) {
    if (page < 2) {
        // UID pages
        return true; // pages 0..1 are always read-only
    } else if (page < 3) {
        // static lock bytes page
        final byte[] data = tag.readPages(page);
        final int lockBits = ((data[2] & 0x0ff) << 8) | (data[3] & 0x0ff);
        if ((lockBits & 0x007) == 0x007) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // page is partially writable
            return false;
        }
    } else if (page < 16) {
        // OTP and user data (lockable through lockbits in page 2)
        final byte[] data = tag.readPages(page);
        final int lockBits = ((data[2] & 0x0ff) << 8) | (data[3] & 0x0ff);
        return (lockBits & (1<<page)) != 0;
    } else if (page < 40) {
        // extended user data (lockable through lockbits in page 40)
        // valid for MIFARE Ultralight C and NTAG203 (not applicable for EV1 products!)
        final byte[] data = tag.readPages(40);
        final int lockBits = ((data[0] & 0x0ff) << 8) | (data[1] & 0x0ff);

        final int relPage = (page - 16) / 4;

        if (relPage < 3) {
            return (lockBits & (1<<(relPage+9))) != 0;
        } else {
            return (lockBits & (1<<(relPage+10))) != 0;
        }
    } else {
        return false;  // unknown
    }
}
```

You could then use this method before you write to the tag:

```
int pageNumber = ...
byte[] pageData = ...
if (!isPageLocked(tag, pageNumber)) {
    tag.writePage(pageNumber, pageData);
}
```

Note that the above method (`isPageLocked()`) would not work for EV1 products in the MIFARE Ultralight and NTAG product lines (e.g. Ultralight EV1 or NTAG21x) since the layout of the extended lock bytes is different for them.